# Powershell how to get the full path of a folder that is deep in the folder structure by knowing only the beginning of the path

Tags: powershell

Would please anyone tell how I can get the path of a specific folder with Powershell command that is about 10, 15 places down in folder structure.

E.g. In the following folder structure

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\...\....\....\....\....\.....\....\....\...\MyFolder
```

Here I have the starting folder path accessible i-e.

```
C:\Folder1\Folder2\Folder3\
```

but I don't know the missing `...\...\....\` folders.

I want to get the full path to the MyFolder. Any help doing that with Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
get-childitem -Path 'c:\Folder1' -Directory -Recurse | ? {$_.Basename -eq 'MyFolder'} | Select FullName
```

Or:

```
get-childitem -Path 'C:\folder1' -Directory -Recurse -Filter 'MyFolder' | Select FullName
```

Comment: Thanks @Scepticalist. Haven't tried the first command but second getting me the full path absolutely fine in Powershell command line But when I use same command inside my C# code along with other powershell comands from a source file, it is not doing anything. Any help on that ?

Comment: The filter command relies on having the PS filesystem provider available. Probably easier to use the first command instead, it's tiny bit slower though.